# calculating sum of a limit of integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation

I am trying to calculate the following expression 
$$
  \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!} \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\{(x,y):2x^2+y^2<n^2 \}}\left( 1  - \frac{2x^2+y^2}{n^2}\right)^{n^2} x^{2m}dx~dy
$$

What I came to understand is as follows:

- Using Lebesgue's Convergence Therorem I can observe, that as $\left( 1  - \frac{2x^2+y^2}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}$ is convergent to $e^{-2x^2-y^2}$ I am integrating something similar to $e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ on an elipse.
- Using observation above I can show that the integral is more then zero. Due to the fact, that the function in question is somewhat similar to  gamma function and just by looking at it, I have a strong suspicion that the whole thing is less then $\infty$.

Help greatly appreciated. The exercise comes from a set of preparatory problems for Calculus II.1 of my teacher, prof Strzelecki, no. 71

http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~pawelst/am2/Analiza_Matematyczna_2/Kolokwia_files/Pula_ver_05a2.pdf